# having problem with react-native navigation | undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation')

Tags: react-native, react-redux, navigation, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

hi i'm working on a new react-native app, but i had some issues with the navigation from a component to a screen.
this is the link for the code on snack: https://snack.expo.io/@mimonoux/my-app-navigation-test

i have already tried this
 `<ButtonCarte  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Carte') } />`.
but it didn't work. please if anyone could help me with this please check the snack link and take a deep look at the easy code i made for my real problem

Comment: In your ButtonCarte component, can you try this : ```<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress()} style={buttonStyle}>```

Comment: thank you for answer, yes i did, it's there, did you took a look at my mini app on expo snack, if not please take a look to have a good idea what i'm struggling with so that you can help me butter, thank you

Comment: May be you didn't understand me. Yes, I saw your code through the link. May be in your ButtonCarte component, try to replace this : ```<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyle}>``` by this ```<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress()} style={buttonStyle}>```

Comment: yes yes thank you so much i did understand you very well my friend, that's exactly what i didn't but still didn't work for me, did you tried it at my code on expo snack and worked for you ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your problem now. With **react-navigation**,
**navigation props** exists in a component when : either the component is configured in your route configuration object that you defined in **App.js**, either you use the withNavigation HOC ( https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html ).

Now in the **Medicine_listDetail** component **this.props.navigation** does not exist since **Medicine_listDetail** does not appear in your route and also the **props** object should not be read by **this.props** in a functional component. You can do one of this two way :

```
const Medicine_listDetail = ({medicine, navigation}) => {
    // i'm passing navigation props comme from parent component that have
    // navigation object
    // ...
}

// OR you can do

const Medicine_listDetail = (props) => {
    const { medicine, navigation } = props;
    // i'm passing navigation props comme from parent component that have
    // navigation object
    // ...
}
```

Hence the following is an attempt at a solution that work for me.

- **Medicine_listDetail** component : i'm passing navigation props come from
  parent component that have navigation object

```
...
const Medicine_listDetail = ({medicine, navigation}) => {

    const {title, coordinate} = medicine;
    const {
        headerContentStyle,
        headerTextStyle,
        cityTextStyle,
        addTextStyle,
        infoContainerStyle,
        buttonsContainerStyle,
        specialityTextStyle,
        buttonStyle,
        textStyle
        } = styles


    return (
    <View>

        <View style={headerContentStyle}>
            <Text style={headerTextStyle}>{title}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={buttonsContainerStyle}>
          <ButtonCarte  onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Carte') }>
          </ButtonCarte>
        </View>
    </View>
    );
};
...
```

- **ButtonCarte** component

```
const ButtonCarte = ({onPress, children}) => {
  const {buttonStyle, textStyle} = styles;

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress()} style={buttonStyle}>
        <Ionicons name={'ios-pin'} size={20} color="white" />
        <Text style={textStyle}>
          Voir La Carte
        </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ); 
};
```

- **Medicin** component : in all_medicine() function, i'm passing navigation object in props of Medicine_listDetail component. So this is the trick.

```
export default class Medicin extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list_allMedicine: data_allMedicine,
      selectedIndex: 0,
    };
    this.updateIndex = this.updateIndex.bind(this);
  }

  updateIndex(selectedIndex) {
    this.setState({ selectedIndex });
  }

  all_medicine() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return this.state.list_allMedicine.map(medicine => (
      <Medicine_listDetail key={medicine.title} medicine={medicine} navigation={navigation} />
    ));
  }

  render() {
    const buttons = ['Tout', '...', '...', '...'];
    const { selectedIndex } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
        <View
          style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <ButtonGroup
            onPress={this.updateIndex}
            selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
            buttons={buttons}
            containerStyle={{ borderRadius:8 }}

          />
        </View>
        <Divider
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
            marginHorizontal: 5,
            height: 2,
          }}
        />
        <View style={{ flex: 5 }}>
          {this.state.selectedIndex == 0 ? (
            <ScrollView>{this.all_medicine()}</ScrollView>
          ) : (
            <Text>test</Text>
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

- At least in App.js, i change the name of carte tab from **Cart** to **Carte** because of your **RootStack** stack.

```
export default createAppContainer(
  createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      Home: {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Ionicons name={'ios-home'} size={25} color={tintColor} />
          ),
        },
      },
      Medicin: {
        screen: Medicin,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: 'Medicin',
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Image
              source={require('./assets/images/Dashboard/drawable-xhdpi/doctor_heart.png')}
              style={{ width: 25, height: 20, tintColor: tintColor }}
            />
          ),
        },
      },
      Carte: {
        screen: Carte,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: 'Carte',
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Ionicons name={'ios-map'} size={25} color={tintColor} />
          ),
        },
      },
    },
    {
      tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: 'black',
        inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
      },
    }
  )
);
```

I test this and it work for me.

Comment: thank you sooo much bro, you saved my life, it's working perfect now :)

Answer (score 0):

try adding this:

```
import { NavigationEvents, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
```

Here is a screenshot of what's available in props in reference to the comments below:

[image: screenshot of where I added a console.log and what it shows in the console]

Here is a screenshot of what I mentioned in the comments. You can see where I added a console.log. It shows in the console that although navigation is in this.props, actions within navigation is empty. I think that is the source of the problem. If you put more console.logs like the one I've done you will see where in the project it loses that information.

Comment: thanks for you answer , i tried to add this line into every page but still it didn't work. did you take a look at my app on expo snack, if not please take a look to understand what i'm struggling with

Comment: Sorry, if that's not it then I'm not sure what's wrong. I had a look at your code. I'm used to react-navigation but not specifically the tab navigator. Maybe it is something specific to that? Is it telling you that this.props.navigation is undefined only where you want to use it or everywhere? Maybe try putting console.logs all over the place and see if it was never defined or if it was but didn't get passed to every component.

Comment: i really don't know if the problem with tab navigator or not but i've tried every solutions  that i can find or think of. yes it's telling me `this.props.navigation is undefined ` only when i add it inside the `ButtonCard` Component otherwise it works fine.
sorry i'm not really used to work with `console.logs` to define the errors so please can you take another look at my code and do it for me please i really need to finish this app soon, i'll really appreciate that

Comment: Ok, for example, on line 32 of the medicine list you could try <ButtonCarte  onPress={() => console.log(this.props)}> and see if navigation is in there. And I would also suggest putting console.log(this.props) inside any of the places you have render, like line 35 of carte.js, 31 of home, and 41 of medicine like this change in medicin.js:  render() { const { navigation } = this.props;
    const buttons = ['Tout', '...', '...', '...'];
    const { selectedIndex } = this.state;  console.log(this.props);
    return (

Comment: I'm going to edit my original answer to add an image of a screenshot.

Comment: thank you so much for your time, i did what you told me, i think the problem is in the `Medicine_listDetail` component where the results shows undefined, but still i have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure. I think react-navigation official documentation is probably your best bet.

Comment: thank you so much for your time, @William Bridge give me the right answer maybe you wanna take a look at it :)